# Is it possible for a Java SwingWorker doInBackground() to wait for an Interim Process to be completed before continuing

Tags: java, swing, thread-safety, swingworker

I am currently using a `SwingWorker` to prevent the Swing GUI from hanging up when it's going a task that takes a while to complete (Web Scraping). Additionally, I'm calling the `publish()` method from `doInBackground()` to send Interim data chunks to the process method as seen on the example code below. However, this is causing me problems as the process method is done asynchronously and can sometimes be overwritten by a new data chunk which causes some of the data to disappear. Is it possible to tell `doInBackground()` to wait for the process/publish method to finish and make sure that the data is processed and used as required before continuing and possibly overwriting the previous data?

```
class validateSources extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            //Do some webscraping here

            //Publish the data to the process method
            publish(webscrapingData);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
        //Use WebscrapingData for something
        Object webscraingData = chunks.get(0);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I noticed that the details I previously gave were not sufficient. The issue I'm currently having is that it's crucial for the data being published from doInBackground() to be fully processed before the next iteration is continued in doInBackground(). Thus, I'm looking for a way to ensure that the code in process() fully completes before doing the next iteration of Webscraping.

Comment: You do not have to invoke `publish` on `doInBackground`. You can call `get()` on `done()`

Comment: Your process method looks to be in error as you should probably iterate through the chunks List within that method, passing the values obtained in the for loop to the GUI (since that code is called on the EDT). You probably should give more details on some of the rest of your code, especially what you're doing with the chunk data once obtained.

Comment: @c0der Apologies for the misunderstanding, I've edited the question with more detail on the issues I'm currently having

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Tasks That Have Interim Results](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html). You will find a statement that says:

*Results from multiple invocations of publish are often accumulated for a single invocation of process.*

```
Object webscraingData = chunks.get(0);
```

You only process a single item.

You need to iterate through all the items in the list.

Comment: It seems that the question I asked lacked some details and there was some misunderstanding on the question. I apologize for this. As written in the edit the problem I'm currently having is that the code in process() must be completed before the next iteration of webscraping in doInBackground(). So I'm looking for a way to ensure the chunk published is fully processed before continuing.

Comment: Then everything needs to be done on the EDT. The whole point of a SwingWorker is that you execute a long running task in the background and then publish data as it becomes available to your GUI. I'm not sure what your definition of webscraping is. Typically it means you parse data on a webpage and then update a GUI with the parsed information. So the two tasks are unrelated.

Comment: I wrote web scraping there since that is the main purpose of the program but I guess it makes the problem less apparent. What I'm essentially doing is I have a ListModel in my GUI. The SwingWorker loops through the list and scrapes the website on the list to see if it should be removed from the list. If It should be removed, it publishes the index of the item to the process method and removes the item from the list with the .removeElementAt method from there. I take into account removed items with an offset variable but it will get messed up if the item is not removed and it continues

Comment: *it publishes the index of the item* - that to me sounds like the design issue. You should publish the item from the ListModel and search the ListModel to find the item before you remove it. Then the index is not needed. So the SwingWorker needs a copy of all the items in the list so it can process them one at time and then publish the items that need to be removed.

Comment: I didn't think of it like that but that seems like a good solution to the problem. Thank you for your help, you really helped save my day!